# Работа с регулярными выражениями в vert.x

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Решил попробовать как vert.x web использует регулярные выражения.Нашел в документации следующее:

```
You can also capture path parameters when using regular expressions, here’s an example:

Route route = router.routeWithRegex(".*foo");

// This regular expression matches paths that start with something like:
// "/foo/bar" - where the "foo" is captured into param0 and the "bar" is captured into
// param1
route.pathRegex("\\/([^\\/]+)\\/([^\\/]+)").handler(routingContext -> {

  String productType = routingContext.request().getParam("param0");
  String productID = routingContext.request().getParam("param1");

  // Do something with them...
});
In the above example, if a request is made to path: /tools/drill123/ then the route will match and productType will receive the value tools and productID will receive the value drill123.

Captures are denoted in regular expressions with capture groups (i.e. surrounding the capture with round brackets)
```

Не совсем понятны разъяснения разработчиков, а именно 2 метода:

```
routeWithRegex(".*foo") -что передается данному методу?часть адреса,общая для всех рутов?к примеру у нас есть руты foo/authentification/username/
```

foo/authentification/accountname/
значит в данный метод передается общая часть рута-foo?

далее `pathRegex("\\/([^\\/]+)\\/([^\\/]+)")` -этот метод принимает шаблон, по которому будет сопоставлять,что пользователь вводит после foo?

и после

```
String productType = routingContext.request().getParam("param0");
      String productID = routingContext.request().getParam("param1");
```

в данном случае,если использовать foo/authentification/username/  то productType=authentification; а productID=username;

я верно понимаю?Потому что эти метода не работают...подскажите пожалуйста кто понял,что в них происходит.